# Como converto formdata para json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tenho o seguinte código:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('user',$("#user").val());
form.append('password',$("#password").val());
var data = JSON.stringify($(form).serialize());
```

porém a var 'data' está ficando com valor nulo, olha o exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/e5p00evx/

A intenção é enviar estes dados utilizando $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:29199/default.aspx?tipo=autenticar",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function () {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (s) {
                console.log('PROGRESSO', s); 
            }, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function (a, b, c) {
        console.log('SUCESSO', a, b, c);
    },
    error: function (a) { console.log('ERROR', a); }
});
```

No lado do servidor já tenho uma estrutura para receber o json e deserializa-lo em objeto.

Comment: O FormData e o `serialize` são alternativos. Como vais enviar esses dados para o servidor?

Comment: Precisas do que está no FormData antes de enviares?

Comment: Na real quero enviar um form com apenas um parametro "query", este terá o json convertido em base64, mas para isto preciso conseguir converter os dados do form inicial para json.

form -> adiciono todas as informações ao form;
data -> converto os dados do form em json;
form -> adiciono um param "chave" com o valor "data" converto em base64;

Comment: A ideia do FormData é ser impermeável a tentativas de manipulação de dados no lado do cliente. Ou seja, quando inseres algo lá dentro já não dá para tirar. Se isso for suficiente usa FormData, senão usando base64 tens de usar `.serialize()` mas passando o elemento do DOM e não o FormData.

Comment: Entendi, ser noob é triste! rsrs... encontrei a solução pro meu problema: https://jsfiddle.net/e5p00evx/2/  é muito mais simples do que eu esperava, precisava encontrar algum meio de gerar um json sem concatenar strings. Obrigado.

Comment: Nesse caso devias ter um elemento `<form>` e depois usar algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/rek9brh0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia do [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData) é ser impermeável a tentativas de manipulação de dados no lado do cliente.

Ou seja, quando inseres algo lá dentro já não dá para tirar. Se isso for suficiente usa `FormData`, isso garante que o browser só fala com o servidor sem olhares indesejados.

Senão usando base64 tens de usar algo para fazer uma string com os dados dos inputs. Podes usar o jQuery (`.serialize()` ou `.serialize()`) e nesse caso tens de dar atributo `name` aos elementos/inputs, e passando o elemento do DOM e não o FormData.

Com FormData:

```
var Dados = new FormData(); 
Dados.append('user', $("#user").val());
Dados.append('password', $("#password").val()); 

// ou passando o <form> diretamente:

var Dados = new FormData(document.querySelector('form')); 

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:29199/default.aspx?tipo=autenticar",
  data: Dados,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Com jQuery (deixo a conversão base64 à tua vontade, pois há várias bibliotecas à escolha):

```
var Dados = $(this).serialize(); 

// ou:

var Dados = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()); 

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:29199/default.aspx?tipo=autenticar",
  data: Dados,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

**jsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/rek9brh0/

**Nota**: [Sobre base 64 na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) <sup>Em Inglês</sup>