# Como eu gero um arquivo JSON para pegar variáveis em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

É uma extensão do Google na qual copio um texto de uma página e gero um JSON com o que foi copiado, porém não estou sabendo como se faz isso corretamente. Consegui fazer essa parte porém não tenho certeza se tenho um JSON.

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(Clique)){
    if(Clique.menuItemId == "Clipenews_paragrafo"){
       console.log("Sucesso");
       var texto = Clique.selectionText;
       $.ajax({
         url: 'localhost',
         dataType: 'json',
         method: 'post'
          data:{ data:JSON.stringify(texto)},
     });
    console.log(texto)
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de conteúdo pode ter esse `Clique.selectionText`? Veja se essa resposta ajuda: [Como converto formdata para json?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205027/86952).

Comment: O Clique.selectionText pega o que foi selecionado e copiado pelo mouse e joga na var texto